# How to prevent race condition between select and update

Tags: multithreading, postgresql, jdbc, locking

I am working on a ledger module. In that process, I had to do these tasks in order

1. select balance from source   (table1 row1)
2. select balance from destination  (table1 row2)
3. modify balances with some logic
4. update balance for source (table1 row1)
5. update balance for destination (table1 row2)
6. commit the changes
7. insert the transactions into a transaction table.

In multithreaded environment, threads get balances before the previous thread updates and commits. 
In Postgres locks are imposed for the row which is being accessed until the thread commits. I see an anamoly in this situation.

Tried using synchronized block for the whole pattern. Didn't help.
can't use SELECT FROM UPDATE because the logic for changing balances depends on other operation.

Here are some logs, before [1] thread goes to update section other threads collect the existing balances.

```
[DEBUG] [2016-12-15 10:49:53,893] [1] - Src Ledger_book_idLB001
[DEBUG] [2016-12-15 10:49:53,893] [1] - Src Balance2500.0
[DEBUG] [2016-12-15 10:49:53,897] [1] - Dest Ledger_book_idLB002
[DEBUG] [2016-12-15 10:49:53,897] [1] - Dest Balance0.0
[DEBUG] [2016-12-15 10:49:53,898] [15] - Src Ledger_book_idLB001
[DEBUG] [2016-12-15 10:49:53,898] [15] - Src Balance2500.0
[DEBUG] [2016-12-15 10:49:53,899] [16] - Src Ledger_book_idLB001
[DEBUG] [2016-12-15 10:49:53,899] [16] - Src Balance2500.0
[DEBUG] [2016-12-15 10:49:53,900] [16] - Dest Ledger_book_idLB002
[DEBUG] [2016-12-15 10:49:53,900] [15] - Dest Ledger_book_idLB002
```

Any help is appreciated :)  Please comment if any specific doubt about the situation.

Comment: You could use `serializable` isolation level.

Comment: If you're updating the `source`, what makes it the `source`? What is the distinction between source and destination?

Comment: @EvanCarroll by source i meant source account... i am trying to debit amount in source and credit in destination.

Comment: *can't use SELECT FROM UPDATE* you mean `SELECT ... FOR UPDATE`? It's hard to understand your logs but I assume your problem is the destination row changes (other row will be updated, not the one which was selected) Am I right?

Comment: Yes it is `select... from update`. I want the thread [15] and [16] in logs to wait untill [1] finishes its update and commit. you can see thht in logs. please refer the expected order and compare with logs. Thanks for responding :)

Answer (score 1):

[From the docs](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/sql-select.html)

> When a locking clause appears in a sub-SELECT, the rows locked are those returned to the outer query by the sub-query. This might involve fewer rows than inspection of the sub-query alone would suggest, since conditions from the outer query might be used to optimize execution of the sub-query.

So you can do this...

You should also read the page on CTE's, especially [DATA-MODIFYING](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/queries-with.html)

```
WITH s1 AS (
  SELECT balance FROM source
  FOR UPDATE
), s2 AS (
  SELECT balance destination
  FOR UPDATE
), u1 AS (
  UPDATE source SET balance = ...
  WHERE... -- potential join to S2 if you need destination
  RETURNING -- whatever you need (if anything)
), u2 AS (
  UPDATE source SET balance = ...
  WHERE... -- potential join to S1 if you need source
  RETURNING -- whatever you need (if anything)
)
INSERT INTO transactions (foo,date) VALUES (bar,now());
```